# Angular: Convert XML to JSON

Tags: angular

I have this method where I receive an XML response from a remote server and I need to convert the XML to JSON so that Angular 2 can work with the data:

```
 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let xml = res["_body"]
    console.log(xml);
    var parser = require('xml2json');
    var json = parser.toJson(xml);
    return json
  }
```

I am trying to use this Node Module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

Now this node module is written in javascript (NOT TypeScript) so I'm not sure if I can even use it in an Angular 2 app.

I am getting this compilation error:

> ERROR in ./~/isemail/lib/index.js 
>   Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve 'dns' in '/Users/user/ebayTool/node_modules/isemail/lib'  @
>   ./~/isemail/lib/index.js 5:12-26  @ ./~/joi/lib/string.js  @
>   ./~/joi/lib/index.js  @ ./~/xml2json/lib/xml2json.js  @
>   ./~/xml2json/lib/index.js  @ ./~/xml2json/index.js  @
>   ./src/app/hero.service.ts  @ ./src/app/app.component.ts  @
>   ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts  @ multi
>   webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

So my question is how to convert XML to JSON in Angular 2 and how I can properly import xml2json Node Module to be used in my project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to bootstrap your application - it comes already with node module to convert xml.

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

So you do not need to add extra modules for this. As it is classic commonJS module - you need use `require` to import it:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
```

So your code can looks like:

```
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
let xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"

parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
  console.dir(result);
});
```

You will receive next output:

[image]

In any cases - if you even do not use angular-clior want to use your preferred module to parse xml - use `require` to load it.

Comment: Thanks! So I did in fact use the Angular CLI to bootstrap my app.

Comment: I am getting the below error when i try to use the xml2js module. 03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130): error ::: Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "events", relative to: app/tns_modules/ 03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130): com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159) 03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130): com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60) 03-17 02:37:48.190: V/JS(7130): com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)

Comment: I'm getting similar issues to @dreamdeveloper - the `xml2js` module has dependencies on `events` and `timers`, which are built in NodeJS modules and not available to Angular on the client side.

Comment: this answer no longer valid as 2023

Answer (score 2):

```
function parseXml(xmlStr) {
    var result;
    var parser = require('xml2js');
    parser.Parser().parseString(xmlStr, (e, r) => {result = r});
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As `xml2js` uses `sax` as parser and is a native c module, I would recommend using [txml](https://npmjs.com/package/txml). In your bundle it will only be 4kb and the api is very clean: `txml.parse(xmlString)`

**Disclaimer** I am the author of txml.

Comment: I am trying to use txml for converting from XML to JSON. txml.parse('<xmlString>') is working fine for me. But I want to use "txml.simplify()", as I need simplified version of JSON object.

I am using exact syntax as mentioned in the documentation.. i.e. 
txml.simplify(txml.parse('<xmlString>');
but this is giving me error : Argument of type (string | tNode)[] is not assignable to parameter of type 'tNode[]'.