# Should i convert the response (Application/XML) to JSON in my front-end or back-end ideally?

Tags: json, angular, xml, spring, rest

i'm placeing a request to a rest api (Spring boot) from my angular 8 project and response of the rest api is of xml format.

Comment: please share your xml example and code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular: Convert XML to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247626/angular-convert-xml-to-json)

Comment: I would always recomment to work with JSON and not xml. If you have to, [txml](https://npmjs.com/package/txml) is a very good option to work with xml data. **disclaimer**:I am the developer of txml.